# UIBlurEffect blur set color

Tags: swift, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I want to place a blur effect on top of a view with gradient. When I do so using the `UIVisualEffectView` combined with the `UIBlurEffect` `light`, I get the following result:

[image: current result]

As you can see, the navigation bar is very bright. I'd like it to not be tinted with white color, or what this might be, but instead actually just blur the background.
I noticed that when dragging down the notification center / lockscreen on iOS 11, the blur is not so bright, even though the background gradient is *exactly* the same:

[image: desired result]

I was thinking this could be done using the `tintColor` property of `UIVisualEffectView`, but changing it did not have any effect whatsoever.

Is there any way I can reproduce the blur effect shown in the image above, using *standard Swift libraries*?

#### Edit

Since there haven’t been *any* responses whatsoever, I’m guessing there’s no way to do it natively.
If someone can recommend a good library, I’m open to that too.
Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/ivoleko/ILTranslucentView

Comment: One approach could be placing a view under the visual effect view with an alpha value lower than 1.

Comment: A transparent view?